# How can I get pipeline details instead of ID in spinnaker?

Tags: continuous-integration, webhooks, spinnaker

I am triggering pipeline through webhook and I got the only event id like below

```json
{
  "eventProcessed":true,
  "eventId":"5464h99-e39a-4da4-8175-342d1af32164"
}
```

and I am trying to get pipeline details through `eventId`, I am not able get the details.

Is there any way to get details using `eventId`?

I am trying to get pipeline details using `eventId` like:

```
https://{spinnaker-url}/pipelines?eventId=9883cv8-e39a-4da4-8175-342d1af32164
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different endpoint and query to retrieve the details of the pipeline execution.

```
https://$spinnaker/applications/$APPLICATION/executions/search?triggerTypes=$TRIGGER_TYPE&eventId=$EVENT_ID
```

Replace the `TRIGGER_TYPE` to webhook.